# SSRS Report cache disable using "rs:ClearSession"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

I found a way to achieve this that using the query string "rs:ClearSession" have to pass in URL.

Below is my code ASP.NET SSRS Reportviewer integarating page,

```
    rptvw.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote; 
    rptvw.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/reportserver"); 
    rptvw.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Northwind/NewNorthwind";

    ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[1]; 
    param[0] = new ReportParameter("CustomerID", txtparam.Text); 
    rptvw.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);

    rptvw.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Question is where should I pass the query string "rs:ClearSession". I tried in above ReportServerUrl and ReportPath but still getting error might be I have done any syntax errors.

Where and how to pass the query string "rs:ClearSession" in URL ?

Comment: I have search many site and blogs but I could not get clear explanation :(

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I'm facing the same problem now.